# android code to upload and download data(for eg.from textbox)to and from the server

Tags: android

could anyone please tel me how to upload the form data (data from Text Box o list) to the server and also to download it in android.Since I am a beginner,i don't know how to upload and download the data.I got the code to upload image to the server.but what I need is for the text data.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [example](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_Get_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=63&aaid=88) out. To understand what is going on, you should try to [understand http](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) first.